# Как определить координаты центра карты Яндекса?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

При загрузке страницы на карте определён центр.
Задача: после того, как он появился, при перетягивании карты его заново получить (т.е. карта перетаскивается, а координаты центра обновляются).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо использовать метод:

```
getCenter
{Number[]} getCenter([options])
Возвращает географические координаты текущего центра карты.
```

https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#method_detail__getCenter